# On the sum of subsets of arithmetic progressions

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, arithmetic-progressions

Let it be an arithmetic progression $A = \{a_1, a_1+k, a_1+2k,...,a_1+(n-1)k : k\in\mathbb N\}$, and let $S=\{x_1,x_2,...,x_r\}$  be some subset of $A$, such that the elements of $S$ are equi-distributed in the sense that the probability that a random element of $A$ belongs to $S$ is positive and defined by a function $P$.

If the above holds, it also seems to hold the following sum formula: $$\sum_{i=1}^{r}x_i = \frac{1}{P}\left(\frac{(a_1+a_r)r}{2}\right)+O(y)$$

Where I have not been able to determine properly a general magnitude of $y$ (although it seems pretty small with the examples I have checked).

I have not been able to prove the above, although I have checked it with some well-known series:

- If $x_i$ is some even number, and we consider the set of natural numbers, we have that $\sum_{i=1}^{r}x_i = 2\left(\frac{r^2+r}{2}\right)+O(y)$
- If $x_i$ is some prime number, and we consider the set of natural numbers, we have that $\sum_{i=1}^{r}x_i = \log(r)\left(\frac{r^2+r}{2}\right)+O(y)$
- If $x_i$ is some square-free integer, and we consider the set of natural numbers, we have that $\sum_{i=1}^{r}x_i = \frac{\pi^2}{6}\left(\frac{r^2+r}{2}\right)+O(y)$

I would appreciate

(i) If necessary (and true), a better definition of $P$ that implies that the conjectured generalization holds.

(ii) A theoretical explanation of why does this hold. I have not been able to prove it, although heuristically makes sense.

(iii) Which could be sharp general bounds for $y$.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

I think I have at least the sketch of a proof, and it seems pretty simple. Just note that, according to the conditions, $x_i=a_i*\frac{1}{P}+O(t)$, and thus the sum formula follows. Therefore, the sharpness of the sum formula depends on the error of the probability function, as we have that $y\leq r*t$.

For instance, if $x_i=a_i*\frac{1}{P}+O(1)$, then $\sum_{i=1}^{r}x_i = \frac{1}{P}\left(\frac{(a_1+a_r)r}{2}\right)+O(r)$.

Comment: $P$ is a constant, right? Not a function. Otherwise nothing makes sense.

Comment: This should be doable by Abel summation.

Comment: @Gary that was my first guess too, but I was not able to conclude that $O(y)$ was small, which in fact happens

Comment: @TonyK could you elaborate on why if $P$ is a function nothing makes sense?

Comment: (i) If the elements of $S$ are equidistributed, that means that the probability is the same for each, doesn't it? So $P$ is a constant. (ii) If $P$ were a function, what would its domain and range be?

Comment: @TonyK $P$ can be a function of $r$, as it happens with prime numbers. For instance, the probability when (uniformly) picking randomly a prime in a subset of $n$ numbers is $1/\log(n)$.

Comment: No it's not $-$ it's $\pi(n)/n$. But in any case, how is that a function of $r$? You are not making any sense at all, that I can see.

Comment: @TonyK you are right, I was using the approximation from PNT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just note that, according to the conditions, $x_i=a_i*\frac{1}{P}+O(t)$, and thus the sum formula follows. Therefore, the sharpness of the sum formula depends on the error of the probability function, as we have that $y\leq r*t$.

For instance, if $x_i=a_i*\frac{1}{P}+O(1)$, then $\sum_{i=1}^{r}x_i = \frac{1}{P}\left(\frac{(a_1+a_r)r}{2}\right)+O(r)$.